# Fullcalendar returning wrong date on dayClick()

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Trying to get the `dayClick()` callback to get the current date. Instead, no matter what I do it seems to `return YESTERDAY` and even shows the wrong day of the week (i.e. it will say "Friday" when the actual day matching the date is Saturday). One really strange thing to note is that this ONLY seems to happen when I click dates around `"today"` (i.e. the highlighted date), sometimes it corrects itself, other times... not.

Here is my JS:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Full calendar
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
        left: '',
        center: 'title',
        right: ''
      },
            dayClick: function(date) {
                console.log(date);
        }
    });
    });
})();
```

And my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>VetPro Dashboard</title>

    <!-- Style Css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../vendor/bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../vendor/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../vendor/bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../vendor/bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/javascripts/calendar_scheduler.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body class="split-background">

    <!-- Start Body -->
    <div class="container-fluid" id="vetpro-dashboard">
      <h1 class="page-header text-center">Dashboard</h1>
      <div class="container">
        <ul id="tabs" class="text-center col-xs-12 font-mobile-17">
          <a href="dashboard_projects.html"><li class="col-xs-2">Projects</li></a>
          <li class="col-xs-2 active">Schedule</li>
          <a href="dashboard_transactions.html"><li class="col-xs-2">Transactions</li></a>
          <a href="dashboard_profile.html"><li class="col-xs-2">Profile</li></a>
          <a href="#"><li class="col-xs-2">Support</li></a>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="container container-border" id="dashboard-schedule">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div id="calendar">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" id="exceptions">
          <div id="scheduler">
            <div id="timepicker">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Body -->
  </body>
</html>
```

And finally, the console log that shows when I click 12/4/15 (date of this post):

```
n {_isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: true, _offset: 0, _locale: R.b, _d: Thu Dec 03 2015 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)…}
```

What is wrong here? What steps can I take to ensure this does not happen in the future? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason adding the "next" and "prev" buttons in the header resolves the issue. No clue why. Hope this helps anyone else having this problem in the future.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  And the next and prev buttons are already there.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
  date.format();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following method to get date :-

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {

    alert('Clicked on: ' + date.format());

    alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);

    alert('Current view: ' + view.name);

}
```

In jquery fullcalendar, You will get previous date, you have to do some process on that date.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback, but why does it only return the day before when I click around today's date? It does not do this for other days in the calendar. This is what has me confused. Normally I could use the same logic to correct this error time and time again, however because it changes unexpectedly, there is very little I can do to counteract this.

Comment: Actually it does do this on other dates.  I find that when I convert `date.format()` into a date (i.e., `new Date(date.format())`, no matter what date I click in the calendar - if I alert the value using dayClick, it's always behind by one day.  I suspect it's a timezone issue.

Answer (score 0):

"I fixed" with:

```
var startdate = moment( date['date'] );
startdate = startdate.subtract(1, "days");
this.dia = startdate.subtract(-1, "days").toString();  // <-- correct date
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this issue with proper format "MM/DD/YYYY", which is a good match for new Date() construction

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
  date.format("MM/DD/YYYY");
}
```